# unable to build Visual Studio Solution from command line

Tags: tfs, msbuild

when I try to issue the build command from visual studio command prompt, I get the following error message:

> Querying enlistment to find matching Build Definition tools path
>
> ERROR. Tools download failed. Failed to find client workspace for
>   given current path e:\code\DisplayApps\Services\InsightsMediator\Dev.
>   Please make sure your current path is mapped into your workspace.

What could be wrong?

Update : this turned out to be a version mismatch problem..the workspace was created using VS 2012 and I as trying to use VS 2010 Command prompt to build. Using VS 2012 command prompt resolved the problem

Comment: It'd help if we knew what you were typing into the command line!

Comment: @Liath I am using msbuild

Comment: Are you supplying a path to your project file you want to build?

Comment: yes, i am giving the path

Comment: In the VS command line, are you in the TFS work directory e.g. C:\tfs\?